# How to check modal pop up visible or not. If not visible bypass the check

Tags: protractor

I am automating an angular based UI. After a successful login to main page, sometimes, based on some logic, a modal based TOUR pops up which is intermittent. I need to click on CANCEL if the modal pop up appears and if does not appears then proceed with rest of execution. But my code fails with

> "ElementNotVisibleError: element not interactable"

when I use below code to validate if element is visible.

```js
browser.switchTo().activeElement().then(function() {
  browser.sleep(1000);
  element(by.id("closeBtn1")).isPresent().then(function(text) {
    if (text) {
      element(by.id("closeBtn1")).element(by.xpath('span')).click();
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: share the html to give more visiblity on the issue

Comment: @ShashankNirmal you can [edit] your question and include code there (or any additional info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you are probably looking for:

```
    browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf($('modal-popup-selector')), 2000)
    .then(async function () {
      $('modal-popup-cancel-button').click(); // if modal did appear then close it
    }, function () {
      // do nothing if modal did not appear within 2000 msc. 
    });
```

This approach works well if you do not know what are pre-conditions for the modal to be shown, but on the other side it will take extra time (2000 msc) for each time the modal did not appear.

Check [visibilityOf](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.visibilityOf) condition docs.